# Is it possible to have templated parameters in an abbreviated function template in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Suppose I have a templated function that takes a templated parameter

```
template <typename T>
void f(std::vector<T> v){ 
        T a;
}
```

and I want to write it using abbreviated function template syntax, like

```
void f2(std::vector<auto x>){
         T a;
}
```

Then the latter does not compile. Is there any way to do it so that it can compile? I can do a workaround such as

```
void f3(auto v){
        using T = decltype(v[0]);
        T a;
}
```

but suppose I want to constrain T using a concept, ie I want something like

```
void f(std::vector<Integral auto T> v){
        T a;
}
```

where I have defined `Integral` as per

```
template <typename T>
concept Integral=std::is_integral<T>::value;
```

Is this possible under C++20? It doesn't appear to be.

Even for the concept, would it not make sense to allow this to be defined as

```
concept Integral=std::is_integral<auto T>::value;
```

Is it just that the language hasn't developed that far yet but will get there eventually?

I guess that it would be possible to define my own concept that allowed only vectors of `int`s, and use that on `f3` above. It would be nice though if I didn't have to if I needed this functionality.

Comment: GCC supports non-standard syntax such as `void f(std::vector<std::integral auto> v)`, but what's wrong with `template<std::integral T> void f(std::vector<T> v)`?

Comment: "*Is it just that the language hasn't developed that far yet but will get there eventually?*" It certainly *shouldn't*. The keyword `template` and template headers are not *evil*. There is nothing wrong with using them. `auto` is a nice shortcut for certain cases, but you shouldn't see a case where you have to use a template header as a failure of the language.

Comment: @NicolBolas, 康桓瑋 Thanks for your responses. I didn't say there was anything wrong with the old/existing syntax but I like the abbreviated templates and it seems logical that it would also be able to handle the example I suggested. Just because the language works currently doesn't mean that it can't be expanded upon. For example, we had to use trailing syntax for function auto return type deduction prior to C++14. It worked, but it is still an improvement that we don't necessarily need to use it now.

Comment: If you use `auto`, it means that you're `don't care` at all about the type of the argument, e.g. `void foo(auto arg)`, or you can use `void foo(std::integral auto arg)`. But in all these cases, it means that you don't care what the exact type of `arg` is. If you really care, then you should use `template<typename T>`, or rather `template<std::integral T>`, but if you tell you neither want to use `template` nor want `T`, that is impossible, because `T` is just a symbol, it can be `T`, it can be `U`, it is not possible to restrict the user that the symbol must be `T`.